# Table has primary key as two foreign keys throws exception when insert the same value for two foreign key in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have three tables:

**tbl.Attribute**:

```
int Id  
int AttributeName
```

**tbl.Product**:

```
public int Id
public string
```

**tbl.ProductAttribute**:

```
int ProductId  
int AttributeId  
string Value
```

When I coincidentally insert `tbl.ProductAttribute` with the same value for 2 foreign keys, it throws an exception:

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhs6P.png)

I've just thought of a way to solve this by inserting a new column to `tbl.ProductAttribute`

```
int ProductAttributeId
```

Then set it as the primary key and use `ProductId`, `AttributeId` as foreign keys. But is that a way to solve this? If it is, is there a better way to solve this without changing the code?

Comment: Please always try to add information as text, not as images. It makes it easier for answerers to copy/paste parts of it into the answer. Also, most questions can't be answered without seeing the code that gives rise to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ProductAttribute` table is many-to-many join table where `ProductId` and `AttributeId` are the composite primary key of that table. So the set of `ProductId` and `AttributeId` must be unique because primary key cannot be duplicate. If you want to insert duplicate values for the set of `ProductId` and `AttributeId` then your `ProductAttribute` model class should be as follows:

```
public class ProductAttribute 
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public long ProductAttributeId { get; set;}

   public int ProductId  { get; set;}

   public int AttributeId  { get; set;}

   public string Value  { get; set;}
}
```

Moreover, If you want the set of `ProductId`,`AttributeId` can be duplicate but the set of `ProductId`,`AttributeId` and `Value` should be unique then your `ProductAttribute` model class should be as follows:

```
public class ProductAttribute 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProductId  { get; set;}

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AttributeId  { get; set;}

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Value  { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A primary key needs to be a unique identifier for the tables rows. If you have duplicates of your shared key then it can't be a primary key. Just add another column for row identification and increment it (or generate guid depending on your needs). You can create non-unique indexes for the foreign keys to aid performance when running joins.